# Check for characters in a string being unique

Tags: javascript

I implemented my algorithm for checking if the string passed in is unique. I feel like my algorithm is correct, but obviously in certain cases it gives the wrong results. Why?

```js
function isUnique(str) {
  let sortedArr = str.split('').sort();
  for (let [i, char] of sortedArr.entries()) {
    if (char === sortedArr[i + 1]) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}

console.log(isUnique('heloworld')) // true
```

Comment: FWIW: `function noDuplicatedChars() { const chars = new Set(); for (let c of str) { if (chars.has(c)) return false; chars.add(c);} return true; }` is a faster alternative.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`return` immediately terminates the function, so only the first iteration if your `for` loop will ever run. Instead, you should check for whether *all* characters are unique (if not, `return false` inside the loop), else `return true` after the end of the loop:

```js
function isUnique(str) {
  let sortedArr = str.split('').sort();
  for(let [i,char] of sortedArr.entries()) {
    if(char === sortedArr[i + 1]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

console.log(isUnique('heloworld'))
```

But it would probably be a lot easier to use a `Set`, and see if its size is equal to the length of the string:

```js
function isUnique(str) {
  return new Set(str).size === str.length;
}

console.log(isUnique('heloworld'))
console.log(isUnique('abc'))
```

See comment, thanks Patrick: if you need to account for characters composed of multiple UCS-2 code points ( etc), call the string iterator and check how many items it returns, which can be done with spread or `Array.from` (because otherwise, `str.length` won't evaluate to the right number of individual characters):

```js
function isUnique(str) {
  return new Set(str).size === [...str].length;
}

console.log(isUnique(''));
console.log(isUnique(''));
```

Comment: Not sure if this matters but for multi-unit code points you get the wrong answer, e.g. `isUnique('') === false`

Comment: The fix is relatively simple though: `return new Set(str).size === Array.from(str).length;`

Answer (score 0):

Only first iteration in your for loop is run (because you always execute 'return'). Instead you can use following code

```js
function isUnique(str, t={}) 
{  
  return ![...str].some(c=> t[c]=c in t)
}

console.log('heloworld =>',isUnique('heloworld'));
console.log('helo      =>',isUnique('helo'));
```

Comment: Why is `r` a parameter?

Comment: r (I rename it to t) is temporary hash map  (define in tricky way as default param)